# Not able to play video in opencv (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I have the following working code in python using opencv (it is tested on another environment), but for some reason I tried to play the video on my computer with Windows 10, Python27 and OpenCV 3.0.0. And it does not play.

**Question:** what can I do to play video in opencv under python 2.7? and what I am doing wrong?

**Here is my code:**

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("output.avi")
cv2.namedWindow("input")
f = True
while (f):
    f, img = cap.read()
    if f == True:
        cv2.imshow("input", img)
        ch = cv2.waitKey(33)
        if ch == 32:
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I have had same problem, have you checked your path variables?

Comment: please check my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the similar issue, and I have fixed the following way:

In order to get your Python 2.7 to play videos using OpenCV library, you need to have the proper OpenCV codex.

To confirm if it is an OpenCV codex issue, first you need to copy `opencv_world300.lib` **TEMPORARY** from you OpenCV library to your Python folder. In my case OpenCV installed under (you should check where your OpenCV installed)

```
C:\lib\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib
```

As mentioned copy it to your Python folder, like again in my case `c:\python27` (find out where your Python folder is located).

Than start to compile your code and see if you can play your video.

If that helps and succeeded, this means your path and environment variables is not correctly set. Therefore, you need to set the following path and environment variables:

Go in your windows `System -> Advance system settings -> Environment Variables` (if you don't know how look at [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm))

And add following in User variables, this is how my variables are setup.

Edit your variable name **path** and add new variable values:

```
%OPENCV_HOME%\x86\vc12\bin
%PYTHON_HOME%
%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts
%PYTHON_HOME%\DLLs
```

So it will look like this in Windows
[image]

```
%OPENCV_HOME%\x86\vc12\bin;%PYTHON_HOME%;%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts;%PYTHON_HOME%\DLLs;....etc.
```

Create new variable name and variable value for following three components:

```
PYTHON_HOME=C:\Python27\

OPENCV_HOME=C:\lib\opencv\build

NUMPY_HOME=%PYTHON_HOME%\Lib\site-packages\numpy
```

So it will look like this in Windows for Python as example and the rest is the same way:
[image]

**Remember!** to restart your console or your IDE so it get updated/fresh variables.

**Note:**

1. This way it should automatically find `opencv_world300.lib` and remember to delete it from Python folder as we move it only to clarify if that was the issue.
2. You need to type the variables manually and **not copy and paste**, some times in Windows you might get a lot of problems by just copying them, I have had that issue. Spcially with (_) Underscore.
3. This solution is valid for OpenCV 3.0.0 and python 2.7.11 and latest windows 10, I have not test it on other environment.

Comment: It worked now for me as well. I was missing %OPENCV_HOME%\x86\vc12\bin in my path. Thanks a lot!